# Summernote Editor - Cannot view image after upload

Tags: php, ajax, summernote

cannot view the uploaded image in summer note after uploading from my folder

```
<script>
    $('#summernote').summernote({
        height: ($(window).height() - 300),
        callbacks: {
            onImageUpload: function(image) {
                uploadImage(image[0]);
            }
        }
    });

    function uploadImage(image) {
        var data = new FormData();
        data.append("image", image);
        $.ajax({
            url: 'Your url to deal with your image',
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            data: data,
            type: "post",
            success: function(url) {
                var image = $('<img>').attr('src', 'http://' + url);
                $('#summernote').summernote("insertNode", image[0]);
            },
            error: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

this is my script in index page .please help me

Answer (score 0):

```
url: 'Your url to deal with your image',
```

In the line above you must write the name of the .php file that handles the file upload and returns (echoes) its url.

For example:

```
url: 'upload.php',
```

Then you must actually create a correct upload.php, of course.